# Express with angular 2 cli

Tags: javascript, angular, express, server

I've tried everything out there. 
I have a very simple ng2 app. This is the file structure:

```
mean
  |- client (where the ng2 app lives)
  | |- dist
  | |- (all ng2 app folders)...
  |- node_modules
  |- routes
  | |- index.js
  |- views
  |- package.json
  |- server.js
```

index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('../client/dist/index.html')
})

module.exports = router;
```

When I run the server.js and navigate into localhost:3000, scripts just dont load:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/inline.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/styles.bundle.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

But mean > client > dist folder has all the js files. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need serve static folder `../client/dist`

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/dist')))

app.route('/*', (req, res, next) {
  // do something
});
```

Comment: @GastonK you should accept this answer since it solved the problem.

Comment: Done @LajosArpad !

Comment: Above answers is correct but If anybody wants end to end steps for this setup you can visit these links 1. https://scotch.io/tutorials/mean-app-with-angular-2-and-the-angular-cli 2. https://javascriptrocks.wordpress.com/2016/06/04/express-with-angular-cli-in-5-minutes/ and follow the steps.